# how would i get the number from this API and place in within a script

Tags: jquery

I'm not very good at this, and my thoughts of this being easy have faded. I have a small simple script up and running and I assigned this var , so each league can insert their # of required starters and the script would do what was needed. But i just asked the web developer to add this numerical value to their API in hopes i can eliminate any manual editing for each league using the script.

```
var RequiredStarters = 9;   // ENTER THE NUMBER OF STARTERS YOUR LEAGUE REQUIRES
```

The value of "9" is now being stored in their API here - http://football30.myfantasyleague.com/2015/export?TYPE=league&L=15787&W=&JSON=0  where you see **starters count="9"** , but i'm clueless on how to get it within my script below and having that # act the same as the var i have set up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var RequiredStarters = 9;   // ENTER THE NUMBER OF STARTERS YOUR LEAGUE REQUIRES

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get('http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?L=%LEAGUEID%&O=06', function (data) {
    $(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function(index, element){
      if($(this).find("tr.oddtablerow, tr.eventablerow").length !== +RequiredStarters && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup"){
        var target = $("#InvalidLineup").find("tbody");
        $(this).find("span a").each(function(){
            target.append("<tr class='oddtablerow'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td class='lineupalert'><a class='lineuplink' href='http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?LEAGUE_ID=%LEAGUEID%&O=02&%FRANCHISEID%'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
        });
      }
    });
      var $lineuprow = $("#InvalidLineup tr");
        if ($lineuprow.length == 1) {
        $lineuprow.text("All Teams Have Valid Lineups").addClass( "oddtablerow" ).wrapInner( "<td class='noevent'></td>" );
}
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ask for it on the page? Provide an API call that returns that number?

Comment: that is what i need help with , no idea how to do an API call and grab that # and assign it as RequiredStaters

Comment: Change `JSON=0` to `JSON=1` and you can work with JSON, which is a bit nicer than working with XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the XML, then parse for the number you need. However, because it is an asynchronous request you want to hold off running the rest of your code until you define `count`.

```
var RequiredStarters; //we might need scope
$.get('http://football30.myfantasyleague.com/2015/export?TYPE=league&L=15787&W=&JSON=0',function(data) {
    RequiredStarters = $(data).find('starters').attr('count');
    //the rest of your stuff here
});
```

Things to watch out for:

1. XML must be hosted on same domain or most browser won't allow the ajax request.
2. Between the XML and HTML ajax requests, it could be a significant amount of downloaded information via ajax that goes to waste. You might consider storing this information in a database instead (assuming that's even an option).

If you prefer to change JSON=1 in the URL, use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` and:

```
RequiredStarters = data[0].league.starters;
```

Good luck!

Comment: so where would the RequiredStarters , find that count value at ? How would i define that count # found to RequiredStarters